# If $A$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix then $\text{tr}(A)^n\geq n^n\det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric and positive definite matrix then is the following relation $\text{tr}(A)^n\geq n^n\det A$ true? How to show this?

Comment: Is $n$ the size of the matrix, or just an arbitrary positive integer? If $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer, then take $A = 1$ and the statement is false for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 of course it is size.

Comment: $n$ is size of the matrix

Comment: **Hint:** In case $n$ is the size of the symmetric positive definite matix, recall they are unitarily diagonalizable, with the eigen-values as the diagonal entries, and $\det(A)$  is the product of Eigen-values. Consider Am-Gm Inequality next ! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n > 0$.

By AM-GM, we have $\dfrac{\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n}$, i.e. $\dfrac{\text{tr}A}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{\det A}$.

Thus, $(\text{tr} A)^n \ge n^n\det A$, as desired.

Comment: Great ,Awesome really a good one

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is symmetric and positive definite then $A$ has its eigen values positive.If $A$ is $2\times 2$ then characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2-(traceA)x+det A=0$  Compute the discriminant which is $(trA)^2\geq4det A$

Comment: And for $n>2$ ?